# Create shortcut for widget in android

Tags: android, widget, shortcut

I have created a widget application. Now I want it to be displayed directly on the home screen, immediately after the application is deployed, like a shortcut, and clicking on the shortcut widget will go to the application.

Can someone suggest me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to add permission INSTALL_SHORTCUT to android manifest xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

private void addShortcut() {
    //Adding shortcut for MainActivity 
    //on Home screen
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

// TO check app is installed first time.

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("ShortCutPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!prefs.getBoolean("isFirstTime", false)){
        addShortcut();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: This method will work if and only if i click on the application icon. And my application is a widget and this can be used only after adding the widget to the homescreen. So this method cannot be used